# Difference between Expo managed project keystore file, and the Google Play upload keystore

Tags: google-play, expo, keystore

I'm building a React Native app using the Expo managed project process. Upon completion, when I run `expo build:android` I am prompted that I need a keystore file associated with my project. I chose to let Expo handle the keystore file process for me. The app builds and I have a .aab file. Great.

Then when I upload to the Play Store, I am prompted by Google Play to ask me if I want Google to store and handle my upload keystore/certificate. This is I believe a requirement now. I also selected yes for this option. It generates its own keystore file and stores SHA-1, MD5 Certificate, etc. These are different than my Expo-produced ones.

So now I have a keystore file generated by Expo that is associated with my app, and an upload keystore file generated by Google Play associated with my app.

I was able to upload my .aab file to Google Play and it is available in the internal testing track which I am currently using to review the app. But I am unclear which keystore file is the one now associated with my app.

Are these the same file or different? If the same, which keystore file prevails? Does Google overwrite the Expo one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Google play is using two sets of certs/keys

- "app signing" one is used to sign application that are in store, unless you are migrating from the old app you will never see that key, it's generated and managed by google, only thing you might need from it is SHA-1 fingerprint that can be used in third party apps to identify your app
- "upload" one is certificate that you need to use to sign your app before uploading it to google. Google needs only public key of that upload certificate.

When you are uploading app to the store google is removing "upload" cert signature and it's signing it with "app signing" certificate

When you are generating app using expo cli it generates random keystore that contains private and public key. At this point keystore is not connected in any way to google account, that connection is established when you upload first application, at this point google saves public key extracted from apk/aab and from this point only applications signed using that keystore can be uploaded to the store